# Как установить слушателя для RecyclerView в Fragment

Tags: java, android

Есть два фрагмента. Один содержит RecyclerView, второй ImageView и TextView.
В зависимости от выбранного компонента в RecyclerView, информация должна меняться во втором фрагменте.
Как и где нужно организовать слушателя, чтобы RecyclerView взаимодействовал с фрагментом 2?

Фрагмент 1.

```
/*всякие импорты и прочее**/

public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
   List<Phone> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
   public OnFragmentInteraction listener;
   private PhoneAdapter adapter;

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
       RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.phones_list);
       adapter = new PhoneAdapter((Context) listener, phoneList);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
       initialize();
       return view;
   }

   public interface OnFragmentInteraction {
       void onFragmentInteraction(String model);
   }

   @Override
   public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
       super.onAttach(context);
       try {
           listener = (OnFragmentInteraction) context;
       } catch (ClassCastException e) {
           throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " не реализует интерфейс");
       }
   }

   private void initialize() {
       phoneList.add(new Phone("Galaxy Fold", "Samsung", R.drawable.galaxy_fold));
       phoneList.add(new Phone("P30 PRO", "Huawei", R.drawable.huawei_p30pro));
       phoneList.add(new Phone("IPhone 11 PRO", "Apple", R.drawable.iphone_11pro));
       phoneList.add(new Phone("One Plus 7 PRO", "OnePlus", R.drawable.one_plu7pro));
   }
}
```

Фрагмент 2.

```
public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {
   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);
   }
}
```

Адаптер

```
public class PhoneAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhoneAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Phone> phones;

    public PhoneAdapter(Context context, List<Phone> phones) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.phones = phones;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PhoneAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PhoneAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Phone phone = phones.get(position);
        holder.image.setImageResource(phone.getImage());
        holder.productName.setText(phone.getModelName());
        holder.productCompany.setText(phone.getCompanyName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return phones.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView image;
        private TextView productName;
        private TextView productCompany;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
            productName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            productCompany = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_company);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListFragment.OnFragmentInteraction {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String model) {
        InfoFragment infoFragment = (InfoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.phone_info_fragment);
        if (infoFragment != null && infoFragment.isInLayout()) {

        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/phones_list_fragment"
            android:name="com.example.constantinekim.fragmentsinteraction2.Fragment.ListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/phone_info_fragment"
            android:name="com.example.constantinekim.fragmentsinteraction2.Fragment.InfoFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: можете попробовать использовать LiveData, тогда в 1 фрагменте можно изменять обьект лайвдаты, а во 2 фрагменте поставить слушатель на LiveData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов - сделать прослойку между адаптером списка и фрагментом где он лежит. Делаем интерфейс-прослойку:

```
interface OnTextClickListener {
    void onTextClick(ExampleItem data);
}
```

дальше в адаптере добавляем его в конструктор:

```
List<ExampleItem> items;
OnTextClickListener listener;

    ExampleAdapter(List<ExampleItem> items, OnTextClickListener listener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ExampleItem data = items.get(position);
                listener.onTextClick(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

дальше в фрагменте ловим данные:

```
class YourFragment extends Fragment implements OnTextClickListener {

    public onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ExampleAdapter(this));
    }

    void onTextClick(ExampleItem data) {
        
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Got: " + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

в вашем случае вы меняете тип передаваемых данных согласно примеру. Дальше после получения отправляете во второй фрагмент типа такого:

```
YourNewFragment ldf = new YourNewFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
ldf.setArguments(args);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();
```

но объект класса мне кажется передать полноценно не получится, так что либо передавайте его в каком-то json либо идентификатор отправляйте чтобы в втором фрагменте восстановить по нему данные.

Comment: чтобы объект передать существует Parcelable